# Select query from three tables SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

The database is Oracle XE .

Let me explain the scenario first ,

Two tables `Movie` and `UserInfo` are in a relationship many to many using the junction table `Rating`.

`Rating` ( `MovieID` (FK) , `UserName`(FK) , `Rating`)

`MovieID` and `UserName` are both respectively the primary keys in the respected tables.

What I am trying to do is make a `select` statement to select the MovieNames from the Movie table where UserName is not equal to the given input. As the MoveID was the FK, but I need to retrieve MovieName if the movie is not already been rated by the GIVEN user, so I guess I may need to make a rather complex joining operation - which I can't figure out or maybe joining two or more different query using where.

Thanks in advance and please if possible give an explanation about the solution.

Comment: Can you post the SQL you have tried?

Comment: And give us create table statements, and sample data and expected result. (sqlfiddle perhaps?)

Comment: actually i have tried different types method . anyway answer is selected .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a classic usecase for the `not exists` operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM   movie m
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   rating r
                   WHERE  r.movideid = m.moveid AND
                          r.username = 'given username here')
```